# The definition of spectral density of stationary process through Fourier transform

Tags: stochastic-processes, fourier-analysis

I recently took up studying elementary stochastic control theory and I have trouble comprehending why exactly is the (cross) spectral density defined in many texts as

$\phi_{xy}(\omega)={1\over{2\pi}} \sum\limits^\infty_{k=-\infty}r_{xy}(k)e^{-ik\omega}$

and

$r_{xy}(k)=\int^\pi_{-\pi}e^{ik\omega}\phi_{xy}(\omega)d\omega$

I've been accustomed to the DTFT definition where the $1\over2\pi$ is a factor in the inverse transformation. Is there particular reason why in most texts I've read about defining the spectral density through covariance, the $1\over2\pi$ is always associated with the summation term?

Especially with white noise this gives $\phi(\omega)={\sigma^2\over{2\pi}}$, and for me it would seem more reasonable to have the variance come straight out from the Fourier transform, without the division by $2\pi$.

Comment: not really an answer but I saw this today in class and the professor said that about half the books put the 2pi by the inverse transform instead, and some even just place a 1/sqrt(2pi) by each of those expressions.